# Google iOS API thumbnailURL: is not working iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-api, google-plus

I'm using Google API for my iOS app, and I have this code

```
    [shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://facebook.com/Uncollectible"]];
```

that works well and embeds the url to my post on Google+ as expected.

But another method with deep-link set doesn't:

```
    [shareBuilder setTitle:@"Uncollectible"
           description:@"Stay cool. Stay debtless."
          thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com/Uncollectible"]];
```

**My code is same as google example**

```
id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];

  // This line will manually fill out the title, description, and thumbnail of the
  // item you're sharing.
  [shareBuilder setTitle:@"New 5k record!"
             description:@"I just ran 5000 meters in 26:16! That's a new record!"
            thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/contribute/person-faye.1bfdab1ab5c0.jpg"]];
  [shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"/races/sf/1234567"];
  [shareBuilder open];
```

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: `thumbnailURL` shoud be an image URL, not a Facebook page.

Comment: @abraham, plz see my detail code with static URL

Comment: You are using `http://facebook.com/Uncollectible` for the URL witch returns an HTML docuemnt not an image.

Comment: @abraham, see below of it, you will find Url as **https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/contribute/person-faye.1bfdab1ab5c0.jpg**

Comment: As understand your question the first code snippet is working with a url, the second is not working with thumbnail and the third was Google's working example? Is not not correct?